# Changing KML Placemark Color with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, kml

Hello Stack Overflow people!!

I honestly don't know if there's a way to do this, but I'm hoping there is since the alternative is even more complicated and I'm not positive how to accomplish it. At the moment, I've got a Google Earth plugin running on a page with some other controls. The page is supposed to show a chart with latency and signal-to-noise data for a modem as well as a grid with tons of additional information to help my ISP do a little better when it comes to trouble shooting modems.

The question I have is: Is there a way in JavaScript to modify the color of a Google Earth placemark without messing with the KML?

I know you can do something like this in the KML

```
<Style id="normalPlacemark">
  <IconStyle>
    <color>ffffff00</color>
    <scale>5</scale>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/wht-pushpin.png</href>
    </Icon>
  </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

But I've been having trouble appending it to the right place in the overall XML using C# or the AddKMLFromString() in the JavaScript (which I'm really unfamiliar with) to get the page to recognize it.

Here's the modified plugin code I'm using at the Moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ge;
    google.load("earth", "1");

    //Create an instance of the Earth
    function init() {
        google.earth.createInstance('gmap', initCallback, failureCallback);
    }

    function initCallback(pluginInstance) {
        ge = pluginInstance;
        ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

        //URL for KML file which is taken directly from Google
        //The KML in question is Google's giant file for weather data
        var href = 'aurlwherewetherdatalives.kml';

        //Use Google's fetch KML method to get the weather KML file and add it to our plugin's instance
        google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function (kmlObject) {
            if (kmlObject) {
                ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
            }
            if (kmlObject.getAbstractView() !== null)
                ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
        });

        //Turn on Country Borders, States, and Cities
        ge.getLayerRoot().enableLayerById(ge.LAYER_BORDERS, true);

        //By default, remoteExists uses True where JavaScript wants true
        var jsRemoteExists = <%= remoteExists.ToString().ToLower() %>;

        //If the remote exists, create a placemark and camera at its location using the
        //the latitude and longitude variables retreived in the c#
        if (jsRemoteExists)
            {
                //Variables have been created
                var lat = <%= CSHARPLat %>;
                var lon = <%= CSHARPLong %>;



                ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);

                // Create the placemark and add it to Earth.
                var placemark = ge.createPlacemark('');

                // Set the placemark's location.  
                var point = ge.createPoint('');
                point.setLatitude(lat);
                point.setLongitude(lon);
                placemark.setGeometry(point);

                // Add the placemark to Earth.
                ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

                var la = ge.createLookAt('');
                la.setLatitude(lat);
                la.setLongitude(lon);
                la.setRange(150000);
                ge.getView().setAbstractView(la);
        }

    }
    function failureCallback(errorCode) {
    }

    function addKmlFromString(kmlString) {
        var kmlObject = ge.parseKml(kmlString);

        ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
    }


    window.onload = init();
</script>
```

Would it be better to find add the above KML to a string in the C# code behind and find the right place to just Add a Style? I've been pouring over Google's API and trying to add it in different places and most of the time it just breaks and doesn't show the weather data or the placemark. The ultimate goal is to change to color of the placemark based on whether the remote is nominal, in alarm, or in warning status. I've looked here and on Google for answers, but nothing seems to do it in the JS and I can't seem to append KML in the right way to get it to change the placemark color. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually figure this out on my own. Hopefully, anyone looking for the answer can find it here.

I saw a lot of things suggesting swapping out images for different colors based on styles, but couldn't find anywhere that described how to do it. The reason is the JavaScript is hidden in the middle of nowhere. Google's API can be... not terribly user-friendly on occasion. So, searchable is better, right? I hope this will help someone out.

In the C# I've got a switch statement with links (absolute paths since locals didn't want to work) to a place where I've got the images stored and pass it to the JavaScript:

```
var statusURL = '<%= CSHARPstatusURL %>';
```

A bit later, you may have to tweak the location so you don't hide any other layers like mine since I was generating the KML dynamically, you want these handy little lines:

```
        // Define a custom icon.
        var icon = ge.createIcon('');
        icon.setHref(statusURL);

        var style = ge.createStyle(''); //create a new style
        style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon); //apply the icon to the style
        style.getIconStyle().setScale(1.5); //set the icon's size
        placemark.setStyleSelector(style); //apply the style to the placemark
```

That's what will allow you to create an icon style, the original way I'd been hoping to do it. Create yourself some images and modify the color saturation in GIMP or something and you're good to go. Cheers!